# Upload two versions of an application on iTunesconnect?

Tags: ios, upload, app-store-connect, testflight

I have to upload two different versions of an application on iTunesConnect at the same time, is it possible to do that? I mean to have the both in beta status?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to test two different versions of one (!) app via TestFlight? It's not possible, you can only test one version at a time.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what about having a version on testFlight and than upload previous version of the same app: ex: I upload version 2.0 on testFlight, and at second time upload version 1.0, does't this work?

Comment: It just "overwrites" the current test version. See my answer below and the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

> At most one prerelease version per platform can be enabled at a time for TestFlight beta testing. Internal and External testers can be testing different prerelease versions at the same time.

**Section**: Upload new builds
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35